# pd.concat keys to separate column

Tags: python, pandas

I have several tables imported from an Excel file:

```
df = pd.read_excel(ffile, 'Constraints', header = None, names = range(13))
table_names = ['A', ...., 'W']
groups = df[0].isin(table_names).cumsum()
tables = {g.iloc[0,0]: g.iloc[1:] for k,g in df.groupby(groups)}
```

This is the first time I've tried to read multiple tables from a single sheet, so I'm not sure if this is the best manner. If printed like this:

```
for k,v in tables.items():    

    print("table:", k)
    print(v)
    print()
```

The output is:

```
table: A
                                          0     1     2   ...     10    11    12
2                               Sxxxxxx Dxxx    21    20  ...     22    19    22
3             Rxxx Sxxxx / Lxxx Cxxxxxxxxxxx     7     7  ...      7     7     7
4  AVG Sxxxx per xxx @ xx% Pxxxxxxxxxxxx 5 X  5.95  5.95  ...   5.95  5.95  5.95
...  
...
...
table: W
                                          0     1     2   ...     10    11    12
6                               Sxxxxxx Dxxx    21    20  ...     22    19    22
7             Rxxx Sxxxx / Lxxx Cxxxxxxxxxxx    30    30  ...     30    30    30
8  AVG Sxxxx per xxx @ xx% Pxxxxxxxxxxxx 5 x  28.5  28.5  ...   28.5  28.5  28.5
```

I tried to combine them all into one DataFrame using  `dfa = pd.DataFrame(tables['A'])`
for each table, and then using `fdf = pd.concat([dfa,...,dwf], keys =['A', ... 'W'])`.

The keys are hierarchically placed, but the autonumbered index column inserts itself after the keys and before the first column:

```
                                                  0     1     2   ...     10    11    12
A       2                               Sxxxxxx Dxxx    21    20  ...     22    19    22
        3             Rxxx Sxxxx / Lxxx Cxxxxxxxxxxx     7     7  ...      7     7     7
        4  AVG Sxxxx per xxx @ xx% Pxxxxxxxxxxxx 5 X  5.95  5.95  ...   5.95  5.95  5.95
```

I would like to convert the keys to an actual column and switch places with the pandas numbered index, but I'm not sure how to do that. I've tried `pd.reset_index()` in various configurations, but am wondering if I maybe constructed the tables wrong in the first place?

**If any of this information is not necessary, please let me know and I will remove it. I'm trying to follow the MCV guidelines and am not sure how much people need to know.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After you get the your tables, Just do

```
pd.concat(tables)
```

Comment: I feel a bit stupid for doing all that other work first. This gets me to the same step, though, where the table names are before the autonumbered index.

Comment: how do I go about switching the two?